# How to add elements of list of linked list in straight order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, function, linked-list

How can I add elements of list of linked list in straight order?
For example, I have list of linked list: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]` and list `new_list` and I wanna add all the elements in order `1->2->3->...->7->8` but not in order `1->4->7->2->5->3->6->8`. For second case I have code:

```
new_list = []
        for array in lists:
            while array:
                new_list.append(array.val)
                array = array.next
```

But how to modify it to get an order as at first case?

Comment: Please make it a [mre].

Comment: Your code (with proper indentation) already outputs the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.

Comment: @kcsquared Probably, yes. That's why they really need to *demonstrate* that it doesn't, with an mre. And then we also wouldn't have had three useless answers that all pretended that the data is ordinary Python lists instead of linked lists...

Comment: @greybeard I don't know if that's a valid edit to the code. Kelly's issue with the existing answers (which I agree with) is that they assume that `lists` has type `List[List[int]]`, when in fact, it is a custom Linked List type with .next and .val attributes. Given that OP hasn't returned to clarify this, or the various other issues with the post, I don't think anyone besides the OP can fix this question.

Comment: @kcsquared Yes, invalid edit, already rolled it back. The input must not be written in the code there like that. Probably the OP is doing this at LeetCode or so, where `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]` is just a convenient text representation of the list of linked lists.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so here's what I have simply done:

```
lists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]
new_list = []
for array in lists:
    for i in array:
        new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
Output: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I don't know why you were using array.next or array.val, however I think you can simply get the list and iterate over it's values and then append it without any problem.

Answer (score -1):

My idea is, I use pop to get the value and then sort the array, you can try my code:

```js
lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
new_list = []
for array in lists:
    while array:
        new_list.append(array.pop())
new_list.sort()
```

So you will get the result which you want :  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]